# Unable to resize my image using Rails 5 and RMagick gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, resize, imagemagick, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to resize an uploaded image to adjust its height (and have the width adjust automatically) with my Rails 5 app.  I have this gem installed

```
gem 'rmagick'
```

and I'm trying to resize like so

```
@person = Person.new(person_params)
if @person.image

  cur_time_in_ms = DateTime.now.strftime('%Q')
  file_location = "/tmp/file#{cur_time_in_ms}.ext"
  File.binwrite(file_location, @person.image.read)
  file = File.open(file_location, "rb")
  contents = file.read
  # Scale image appropriately
  @person.image = contents.resize_to_fit(1000000, Rails.configuration.max_img_height)
```

but on the

```
@person.image = contents.resize_to_fit(1000000, Rails.configuration.max_img_height)
```

line, I get teh error

```
undefined method `resize_to_fit' for #<String:0x007fab53660c78>
```

What's the right way to resize my image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file with RMagick first:

`img = Magick::Image::read(file_location).first`

And then you can use `resize_to_fit`:

`@person.image = img.resize_to_fit(75, 75)`

Here is a good guide to [common tasks](https://rmagick.github.io/comtasks.html)

Comment: I'm doing that already, right?  The "content" variable comes from "contents = file.read"

Comment: Thx for the update.  I'm getting a new error taht I opened a separate question for -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48389193/getting-unable-to-load-module-when-trying-to-scale-image-with-rails-imagemag , b/c I think its unrelated to what you've recommended.  But I'd like to solve the other error to be certain.

Comment: As you see in the error: `undefined method `resize_to_fit' for #<String:0x007fab53660c78>`  -- `contents` is right now a string - that's why i wrote this recommendation, to be sure, that you have used RMagick the right way, because then it would not be a string.