# Getting "unable to load module" when trying to scale image with Rails / ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, resize, imagemagick, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to scale an uploaded image that I'm uploading through a form.  I have a Mac (High Sierra) and am using Rails 5.  I'm currently using this code and the "rmagick" gem to handle it

```
@person = Person.new(person_params)
if @person.image

  cur_time_in_ms = DateTime.now.strftime('%Q')
  file_location = "/tmp/file#{cur_time_in_ms}.ext"
  File.binwrite(file_location, @person.image.read)
  file = File.open(file_location, "rb")
  contents = file.read
  # Scale image appropriately
  img = Magick::Image::read(file_location).first
  @person.image = img.resize_to_fit(1000000, Rails.configuration.max_img_height)
```

but when I upload the image, I get the error

```
unable to load module `/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.9.2-4/lib/ImageMagick//modules-Q16/coders/png.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1300
```

on the line

```
img = Magick::Image::read(file_location).first
```

I ran

```
brew update && brew install imagemagick
```

without any errors so I'm not sure what the issue is.

**Edit:** In response to the ansewr given, here's what happened when I tried to run a "bundle install

```
checking for presence of MagickWand API (ImageMagick version >= 6.9.0)... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.2_1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:104:in ``': No such file or directory - MagickWand-config (Errno::ENOENT)
    from extconf.rb:104:in `configure_compile_options'
    from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
    from extconf.rb:548:in `new'
    from extconf.rb:548:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.4.0/rmagick-2.16.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/nataliab/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-17/2.4.0/rmagick-2.16.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.16.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rmagick
```

Comment: You have a double `//` in your path.. : ImageMagick//modules-Q16

Comment: Look at this link: [Using Image Magick with rails](https://www.gra2.com/article.php/using-rmagick-imagemagick-rails) - he's talking about setting some enviroment variables to install the gem. Maybe that's the problem (be aware - the articel is 10 years old)

Comment: You have required the gem in the top of the controller, right?

Comment: The error could be due to a variety of issues. Can you try removing rmagick `gem remove rmagick`, then installing imagemagick with x11 i.e. `brew install imagemagick --with-x11` and reinstalling rmagick

Comment: @Dipil, Thx for your suggestion but trying that results in the same error.  I even restarted my whole system after running brew install and then re-installing the gems.

Comment: @PeterAndersen, I actually didn't have the "require 'rmagick'" at the top of the file, but even after adding that I still get the error from my question.

Comment: what about installing `imagemagick` as told from @Dipil

Comment: Be sure to install ImageMagick 6 or 7, whichever is compatible with your Rmagick

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `libpng` module cannot be loaded. I would suggest trying to reinstall `imagemagick` from source, and then reinstall and link `libpng`.

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
brew uninstall libpng
brew install libpng
brew link libpng
```

Comment: Hi, I ran these steps but when it got time to start my server, I got an error complaining about not having "rmagick".  So I ran "bundle install" and got the errors you see in the edit to my question.

Comment: Try reinstalling the gem as well `gem uninstall rmagick && gem install rmagick`